# How to set focus for button in KeyPressEvent for key_up, key_down. QT

Tags: c++, qt, button, focus

I have a Form with buttons called `"Up"`, `"Down"`, etc.

I need to process keyboard buttons (`arrow_up`, `arrow_down`, etc). Parallelly I want to set focus for relevant buttons.

**For Example:** If I pressed the `arrow_down` button on keyboard then the `"Down"` button would be a focus on my Form.

My variant how to do this:

```
bool ClientWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *event= dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);
        switch(event->key()) {
            case Qt::Key_Up: ui->up->setFocus(); ;break;
            case Qt::Key_Down: ui->down->setFocus(); break;
            case Qt::Key_Left: ui->left->setFocus(); break;
            case Qt::Key_Right: ui->right->setFocus(); break;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

But, focus isn't set, and

1) If I return **true** from `eventFilter` then focus wouldn't set.

2) If I return **QObject::eventFilter(obj, event)** then focus would be transferred to next Object.

How to set focus for the relevant button?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think I understand what you're asking, but please provide a more complete example. What is ClientWindow? What is the `eventFilter` set on (the QObject)... or are you setting a filter on itself (which isn't the way to do it)? What else (widgets/layouts) is in ClientWindow or the filtered object, or anywhere else in the UI which could be stealing key presses? As you see, many questions, best answered with a complete (but minimal) example. Focus handling can be a bit tricky at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to change a standard feature of Qt (arrow keys move focus just like TAB key does), you may want to try an extreme solution.

The point is: are your arrow key press events even being filtered at all? My guess is no. Something *above* (or *before*) the widget is consuming them and keeps the standard behavior unchanged (focus move from button to button according to their tab-indexes as usual).

I would try installing your filter onto the `QApplication` object, in the widget constructor this way:

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);
```

The filter should look like this:

```
bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        if(qApp->activeWindow() == this)
        {
            QKeyEvent *event= dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);

            switch(event->key()) {
            case Qt::Key_Up: ui->up->setFocus(); break;
            case Qt::Key_Down: ui->down->setFocus(); break;
            case Qt::Key_Left: ui->left->setFocus(); break;
            case Qt::Key_Right: ui->right->setFocus(); break;

            default:
                return qApp->eventFilter(obj, e);

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return qApp->eventFilter(obj, e);
}
```

Please notice this line:

```
if(qApp->activeWindow() == this)
```

which should prevent the rule in the filter to be applied *whenever* the arrow keys get pressed (i.e. when the widget isn't the topmost one). You can ignore that, if your application hasn't other widget than this one.

Final advice: try to never change the standard UI behavior. Users do expect things to work as usual, and solutions that look absolutely *cool* to the developer, sometimes (often), brings no improvements at all and only confuse the user.

Comment: Seem like overkill to me. Every single application event will be running through this filter. Could be useful to check if key events are being captured somewhere up the chain I s'pose. The "correct" way to implement key handling in a widget is to re-implement `QWidget::key*Event()` methods. Or at a higher level in `QWidget::event()`. Using an event filter to monitor events on itself doesn't really make sense IMHO. That's why I was asking the OP to clarify. It seems more likely that something else is stealing focus after `setFocus()` calls, especially since the event is never `accepted()`.